# Correct spacing in tikz-cd with kpfonts

Tags: tikz-cd, kpfonts

Tikz-cd does not respect spacing correctly when used with kpfonts. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[rr, "f(x) \otimes g"] && B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: With kpfonts]
with kpfonts versus
[image: With CM]
with CM.
How to fix this?

Comment: It is not `tikz-cd`, it is the font size, also `$\scriptstyle f(x) \otimes g$` (without `tikz-cd`) gives the same result.

Comment: An image would allow us to confirm that we’re reproducing the same bug on our systems.

Comment: You are right, the issue seems to come from scriptstyle.

Comment: Not a bug; try `\xrightarrow{f(x)\otimes g}` and you'll see the same spacing around `\otimes`. TeX doesn't add space around operation or relation symbols in `\scriptstyle`. If you don't load `kpfonts` you'll have the same. In any case, don't use the `minimal` class for examples, but `article`.

Comment: @egreg, I have added a picture of the case where I remove kpfonts.

Comment: @DamienL The bounding box of `\otimes` is a bit looser in Computer Modern than in `kpfonts`. The latter family of fonts generally uses tight bounding boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `tikz-cd`. If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
A\xrightarrow{f(x) \otimes g} B
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[rr, "f(x) \otimes g"] && B
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

The `\otimes` symbol in `kpfonts` has a tight bounding box.

It may make sense to add some space around the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathchardef\latexotimes\otimes
\renewcommand{\otimes}{\mathbin{\mspace{1mu}\latexotimes\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}

\[
A\xrightarrow{f(x) \otimes g} B
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[rr, "f(x) \otimes g"] && B
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]